# What to use to denote numbered list with hierarchy in Academia (ie. numerals, alphabets, roman numerals)

Tags: publications, etiquette, writing, writing-style

Perhaps I'm missing the right search words/terms. I recall there was a way to use a numbered list and how to structure it's hierarchy but can't seem to find the recommended way on the internet. How far does it go until it repeats? (if it varies for different styles please can we focus on APA style)

For example:

[image]

Comment: I found this: https://editorsmanual.com/articles/lists/ . It doesn’t answer your literal question but has some related advice.

Comment: Thank you @DanRomik, the multi level list seem helpful(https://editorsmanual.com/articles/lists/#multilevel-lists). 

I wonder if it's APA or research compliant. I also wonder what happens if we go further down the levels.

Comment: @nvs0000 "Research compliant" is not a thing in this context, if you want a definitive answer for APA style I recommend you track down a copy of their published style guide. Dan Romik's link features five nested levels; in my opinion, any more than that would be quite difficult to read and would be best avoided.